# Как спрятать scrollbar если высота меньше чем

Tags: html, css

Как спрятать scrollbar, если высота div не превышает например 150px?

```css
.test {
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.test p {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
</div>
<div class="test">
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
  <p>4</p>
  <p>5</p>
  <p>6</p>
  <p>7</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.test {
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.test p {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
</div>
<div class="test">
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
  <p>4</p>
  <p>5</p>
  <p>6</p>
  <p>7</p>
</div>
```